# Category of Canadian Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, canada

I am a student. I have been invited to attend a conference at Canada. It is an all paid trip so the company will bear all the expenses. I am confused about which category of visitor visa I should apply for. The two categories that apply to my case are:

1) Business: Conferences come under "Business" category but since I am a student, I have no employment to show for this category.

2) Tourist: If I apply under "Tourist" category, I don't have any assets or significant amount of money to show.

Please suggest the best category for my case.